# Passing JSON object from Java to Javascript through JSP tag

Tags: java, json, jsp, jstl

I have a service A in the java server side of my application that returns a JSON object, and I need to consume that object in javascript side to call another service B.

The platform is a bit complex, having two applications based on Stripes and Spring packed under the same war and sharing a lot of code.

The solution I have so far is creating a JSP tag that access the JSON object and puts it in a variable:

```
   @Override
   public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
       pageContext.setAttribute(var, SERVICE_A_JSONOBJECT, scope);
       return SKIP_BODY;
   }
```

This works well, but the jstl variable is converted to String, so in the javascript call I have to use JSON.parse.

Is there any way to improve this by passing the JSON object to javascript without being converted and then parsed?

NOTE: Since they are two apps, I would like to avoid using the session, because then I would need to duplicate the code

Comment: how are you outputting the json?

Comment: A JSON string constitutes a valid JavaScript literal. Just use `var foo = ${jsonString};`.

Comment: it is, but the javascript is expecting a JSON Object, not a String representation of a javascript object, doesn`t work

Comment: Suppose the Java String contains the characters `{"foo": "bar"}`, and it's stored in the attribute `attr`. The line `var foo = ${attr};` will generate the following JavaScript code: `var foo = {"foo": "bar"};`. And this is valid JavaScript, which assigns a JavaScript object to the variable `foo`. There's no JavaScript string parsing involved.